# Java - Iterate over all files in directory

Tags: java, file, recursion

I want to find all the `txt` files in directory and in the nested sub-directories. If found, I want to move that from one location to another.

The below code works fine, if i don't have any nested sub-directories.

The problem with the below code is, Once it find the nested directories it return the file only from that particular nested sub-directory.
But I want all the `txt` files in my directory ( parent and its nested sub-directories ).

```
public class FilesFindingInDirectory {
    static ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
    static File fileLocation = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        File filePath = new File("C:\\Users\\Downloads");

        File[] listingAllFiles = filePath.listFiles();

        ArrayList<File> allFiles = iterateOverFiles(listingAllFiles);


                for (File file : allFiles) {
                    if(file != null) {
                        String fileName = file.getName();

                        String sourceFilepath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                        File targetFilePath = new File("D:\\TestFiles");
                        String targetPath = targetFilePath.getPath();

                        Files.move(Paths.get(sourceFilepath), Paths.get("D:\\TestFiles\\" + fileName)); 
                    }

                }
            }


public static ArrayList<File> iterateOverFiles(File[] files) {


        for (File file : files) {

            if (file.isDirectory()) {

                iterateOverFiles(file.listFiles());// Calls same method again.

            } else {

                fileLocation = findFileswithTxtExtension(file);
                if(fileLocation != null) {
                    System.out.println(fileLocation);
                    al.add(fileLocation);
                }


            }
        }

        return al;
    }

public static File findFileswithTxtExtension(File file) {

        if(file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith("txt")) {
            return file;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though the code can be improved on the recursion result collecting part, I tested your code and it works fine. Can you elaborate more what issue you see? Or provide an example? I tested the code with a directory containing 2 txt files and another directory which contained 2 other text files and it worked fine. The only thing I can imagine is if the filenames are same, they end up being overwritten in the final destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are properly calling the function recursively, but you're then ignoring its return value. Instead, you should append it to the result list:

```
public static List<File> iterateOverFiles(File[] files) {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            result.addAll(iterateOverFiles(file.listFiles()); // Here!
        } else {
            fileLocation = findFileswithTxtExtension(file);
            if(fileLocation != null) {
                result.add(fileLocation);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You're already using the nio Files API to move the files, why not using it to iterate over the files?

```
 List<Path> txtFiles = Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Downloads"))
                            //use to string here, otherwise checking for path segments
                            .filter(p -> p.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you don't need that intermediary list, you could as well run your move operation in a `foreach` terminal operation

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Downloads"))
     .filter(p -> p.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
     .forEach(p -> {
        try {
            Files.move(p, Paths.get("D:\\TestFiles", p.getFileName().toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Our `Files.find` which provides a parameter for the filtering.

Comment: The OpenJDK documentation for `Files#walk(Path)` has an API note that states *"This method must be used within a try-with-resources statement or similar control structure to ensure that the stream's open directories are closed promptly after the stream's operations have completed."* Does this mean it's necessary to wrap the code in your answer with a try-with-resources statement? Or is this requirement covered by the use of the functional API/streams?

Comment: It seems the API note above was added in Oracle's SE 9. The SE 8 [`Files#walk(Path, FileVisitOption)` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) states *"The returned stream encapsulates one or more DirectoryStreams. If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed. Operating on a closed stream will result in an IllegalStateException."*

Answer (score 4):

From your recursive function remove this line:

```
return al;
```

change this line to just call the recursive function:

```
ArrayList<File> allFiles = iterateOverFiles(listingAllFiles);
```

to

```
iterateOverFiles(listingAllFiles);
```

and finally change your for loop to iterate over the static field al.

```
for (File file : allFiles) {
```

to

```
for (File file : al) {
```

Explanation: There are numerous ways to write recursion for this problem. In this case you have a global variable for collecting the results. Each iteration should add to that global result, and simply return. At the end of all recursion calls, the global variable will contain all the results.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over a directory, skipping any non-directory entries and entries that do not have the desired extension. Add all files with the correct extension to a result, and do that recursively for each directory.

```
public class FilesFindingInDirectory {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    File filePath = new File("C:\\Users\\Downloads");


    Collection<File> allFiles = findFiles(filePath, ".txt");
    allFiles.forEach(file -> {
                    String fileName = file.getName();

                    String sourceFilepath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    File targetFilePath = new File("D:\\TestFiles");
                    String targetPath = targetFilePath.getPath();

                    Files.move(Paths.get(sourceFilepath), Paths.get("D:\\TestFiles\\" + fileName)); 
                }

            }
        }

public static List<File> findFiles(File dir, String extension) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(f -> f.isDirectory() || f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(extension);
    ArrayList<File> result = new ArrayList<>();  
    if (files != null) {
       for (File file : files) {

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            result.addAll(findFiles(file, extension);
        } else {
            result.add(file);
        }

    }

    return result;
  }
}
```